# perl: use Getopt::Long to set Class::Struct fields?

Tags: perl, getopt

Can I use Getopt::Long to set struct fields?

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use Getopt::Long;
use Class::Struct foo [ a => '$', b => '$' ];

my $foo = foo->new();
GetOptions("a=i" => \$foo->a, "b=i" => \$foo->b);
```

does not seem to work, "-a 10" does not seem to set `$foo->a`.

obviously, I would rather avoid

```
GetOptions("a=i" => sub { $foo->a($_[1]); }, ...);
```

also, I would rather keep the struct foo an array, not a hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\$foo->a` will be a reference to the return value of `$foo->a`, which is certainly not what you want.

You can probably use the ability of `GetOptions` to [store the values in a hash reference](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash), then pass that to your object's `new`:

```
my $opt = {};
GetOptions($opt, 'a=i', 'b=i', ...)
my $foo = foo->new(%$opt);
```

Comment: what if my fields are like "foo_bar_baz" and options like "--foo-bar-baz"?

Comment: When I use `Getopt::Long`, I just store all the option values in `%Opt`, with the keys matching the option names. So I'd call `GetOptions(\%Opt, 'foo-bar-baz=i')`, and then refer to `$Opt{'foo-bar-baz'}`. Keeping the option names and field names consistent avoids confusion.